# Calculate time to execute a function

Tags: c++, time, time.h

I need to calculate the execution time of a function.

Currently, I use time.h

At the beginning of the function:

```
time_t tbegin,tend;
double texec=0.000;
time(&tbegin);
```

Before the return:

```
 time(&tend);
 texec = difftime(tend,tbegin);
```

It works fine but give me a result in texec as a integer.

How can I have my execution time in milliseconds ?

Comment: read up on `std::chrono`, but watch out for timing gotchas on different operating systems. For example, Windows loves giving time in increments of 15.625 ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the simple programs have computation time in milliseconds. So, I suppose, you will find this useful.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();
    // Executable code
    clock_t stop = clock();

    double elapsed = (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed in ms: %f\n", elapsed);
}
```

If you want to compute the run-time of the entire program and you are on a Unix system, run your program using the `time` command, like this: `time ./a.out`

Comment: You have to be careful when using this approach in multi-core environments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda with `auto` parameters in C++14 to time your other functions. You can pass the parameters of the timed function to your lambda. I'd do it like this:

```
// Timing in C++14 with auto lambda parameters

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// need C++14 for auto lambda parameters
auto timing = [](auto && F, auto && ... params)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::forward<decltype(F)>(F)
    (std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...); // execute the function
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
               std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
};

void f(std::size_t numsteps) // we'll measure how long this function runs
{
    // need volatile, otherwise the compiler optimizes the loop
    for (volatile std::size_t i = 0; i < numsteps; ++i);
}

int main()
{
    auto taken = timing(f, 500'000'000); // measure the time taken to run f()
    std::cout << "Took " << taken << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    taken = timing(f, 100'000'000); // measure again
    std::cout << "Took " << taken << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

The advantage is that you can pass any callable object to the `timing` lambda.

But if you want to keep it simple, you can just do:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
your_function_call_here();
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto taken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
std::cout << taken << " milliseconds";
```

If you know you're not going to change the system time during the run, you can use a `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead, which may be more precise. `std::chrono::steady_clock` is however un-sensitive to system time changes during the run.

PS: In case you need to time a member function, you can do:

```
// time member functions
template<class Return, class Object, class... Params1, class... Params2>
auto timing(Return (Object::*fp)(Params1...), Params2... params)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    (Object{}.*fp)(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
               std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
};
```

then use it as

```
// measure the time taken to run X::f()
auto taken = timing(&X::f, 500'000'000);
std::cout << "Took " << taken << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
```

to time e.g. `X::f()` member function.

Comment: How to do this one for function methods , when I pass the timing(Object.Method1) it return error  "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Comment: @RobinAtTech You can use `std::bind`, like `using namespace std::placeholders; X x; auto f = std::bind(&X::f, &x, _1);` See full example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4b75548ec9b5154

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function like this [source](https://github.com/arhuaco/junkcode/blob/master/emqbit-bench/bench.c):

```
typedef unsigned long long timestamp_t;

static timestamp_t
timestampinmilliseconf ()
{
  struct timeval now;
  gettimeofday (&now, NULL);
  return  now.tv_usec + (timestamp_t)now.tv_sec * 1000000;
}
```

Then you can use this to get the time difference.

```
timestamp_t time1 = get_timestamp();
// Your function
timestamp_t time2 = get_timestamp();
```

For windows you can use this function:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctime>
#endif

typedef long long int64; typedef unsigned long long uint64;

/* Returns the amount of milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch. Works on both
 * windows and linux. */

int64 GetTimeMs64()
{
#ifdef WIN32
 /* Windows */
 FILETIME ft;
 LARGE_INTEGER li;

 /* Get the amount of 100 nano seconds intervals elapsed since January 1, 1601 (UTC) and copy it
  * to a LARGE_INTEGER structure. */
 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
 li.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
 li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

 uint64 ret = li.QuadPart;
 ret -= 116444736000000000LL; /* Convert from file time to UNIX epoch time. */
 ret /= 10000; /* From 100 nano seconds (10^-7) to 1 millisecond (10^-3) intervals */

 return ret;
#else
 /* Linux */
 struct timeval tv;

 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

 uint64 ret = tv.tv_usec;
 /* Convert from micro seconds (10^-6) to milliseconds (10^-3) */
 ret /= 1000;

 /* Adds the seconds (10^0) after converting them to milliseconds (10^-3) */
 ret += (tv.tv_sec * 1000);

 return ret;
#endif
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/pabennett/glblox/blob/master/lib/timeit.cpp)

Comment: Well, that's Linux only.  What about Windows and/or portable solutions?

Comment: @MooingDuck:- For windows: https://github.com/pabennett/glblox/blob/master/lib/timeit.cpp

Comment: Linux version's giving time in us.

Answer (score 0):

in the header `<chrono>` there is a
class `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` 
that does what you want. it's a bit involved to use though;

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
// do calculation here
auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto diff = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1); 
// now elapsed time, in seconds, as a double can be found in diff.count()
long ms = (long)(1000*diff.count());
```