# What is the best way to calculate the running time of a multi-process program?

Tags: c, multithreading, time, multiprocessing

I have a `multi-process` program written in `C`, where the parent forks a number of children, and I need to calculate its running time, and compare it with the running time of a `multi-threaded` program which does the same task as that by the `multi-process` one.

Except using `time.h`'s `clock` function (which reports CPU time, thus may report more time in a `multi-threaded` program if no. of threads is high), what else can I use to calculate both programs' running time for comparison purposes ?

I am currently using `time ./a.out` to calculate their running time.

Comment: clock_gettime may work for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs

Comment: What is your definition of "running time"?  Do you mean the wall-clock time it takes between the time the first child process is initiated and the last child process terminates?  do you mean the aggregate wall-clock time used by all child processes?  (e.g. if two processes took 5 seconds to complete, the aggregate wall-clock time would be 10 seconds)  Or do you mean the amount of cpu time accumulated by all the child processes?

Comment: I mean the wall-clock time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use gettimeofday() from the time library on the main thread and it should give you its elapsed time.

If you run it on a thread it will only reply back with that particular threads elapsed time.