# What Web-Engines do I've aviable when developing a C# Application in Windows?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to know what are the most popular Web-Engines to use in a Desktop Aplication using C# and WinForms.

Can you suggest some ?

**edit:** I've edited the question, I think it's OK now.

Comment: How about [Gecko?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88/is-gettimeofday-guaranteed-to-be-of-microsecond-resolution) But your question borders on "Not Constructive;" can you make it more specific, perhaps by outlining more clearly what you want to achieve?  There's no such thing as "best," there is only that which most adequately fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Well, the question is already attracting one-liner answers, so I'm closing it.  If you can improve the question by editing, flag it requesting a re-open, and we'll consider it.

Comment: If you would change the phrase "the best" to "most mature" - it probably would do.

Comment: I would add what kind of "web-browser" you are trying to make any why IE isn't acceptable.

Comment: Can the guy who downvoted please explain what can I do to improve the question ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/about/).

It has a good .NET/WPF support.

Comment: Wow... that looks... Awesomium !

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) ([GitHub Download](https://github.com/webkitdotnet))