# Get current timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: php, timestamp, microtime

I want to get current timestamp with milliseconds in PHP something like below, in JavaScript I use `Date.now()`

```
1436030635348
```

I tried something like below:

```
$time = str_replace(".","",microtime(true));
```

But sometime it is not working properly. Like it prints one or two digits less.

Comment: do you need the timestamp in milliseconds or in microseconds? the title says one thing and the actual question another

Comment: it is rounding problem. Trailing zeros are not echoed, `str_pad (str_replace(".","",microtime(true)) , 14, 0 )`

Comment: @AlexAndrei : sorry i need in milli seconds

Comment: Then considering the result of `microtime()` is in second, all you need to do to convert it to the millisecond by multiplying it by a 1000 :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can print less digits, because it is a float value. So if you get `1234.0005`, that `.0005 actually means 500 microseconds. The zeroes after the 5 are lost because it's still an unformatted float value.

The function `microtime` is based on the system call `gettimeofday()`, which also isn't accurate to the microsecond. Commonly it's accurate to 10 microseconds. See also [Linux - Is gettimeofday() guaranteed to be of microsecond resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88/is-gettimeofday-guaranteed-to-be-of-microsecond-resolution).

-edit- I see the specs in your question have changed from microseconds to milliseconds.

To get the float value you have as an integer, you can multiply by a value. The float value represents seconds. Multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds or 1,000,000 to get microseconds. Since the specs (now) say milliseconds, you should multiply by 1000. 10k will give you accuracy of 1/10ms = 100μs. A millisecond is one thousandth of a second. A microsecond is one millionth of a seconds.

Long story short, to get the time in integer milliseconds, use this:

```
$milliseconds = intval(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Note: there is a reason why you get the time as a string or a float by default. The reason is that on 32 bit systems, PHP's integer is also 32 bits and is not large enough to contain the timestamp including milliseconds and microseconds. So this solution will only work well on a 64 bit system.

Comment: so how can I preserve zero .. and any other function to get timestamp without decimal ?

Comment: Instead of replacing the `.` you can multiply by a million.

Comment: lol million or 10k ?10k seems to work

Comment: A million for microseconds. I see you've changed the specs to milliseconds, so then you should divide by 1000. 10k will give you accuracy of 1/10ms = 100μs. A millisecond is one thousandth of a second. A microsecond is one millionth of a seconds. I've updated the answer.

Comment: So in that case my answer was correct right?

Comment: Why do I get output like `1.47658187028E+12`? I changed to `intval(microtime(true)*1000)` and it is fine now.

Comment: @JamesWayne You get that output, because the result of `round` is a float, which tends to be displayed this way if its very large. The (small) difference is that `round` rounds, while `intval` truncates, so the outcome between the two could differ one millisecond, but that's probably not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeStampData = microtime();
list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', $timeStampData);
$msec = round($msec * 1000);

$result = $sec . $msec;
```

Something like this

But note, that js date.now() return time in MILLIseconds, not MICROseconds

Comment: so how to get timestamp in milliseconds in php ?

Comment: yea i need in milli seconds

Comment: example above show how to get it. if u want u get timestamp with microseconds - you should change this round($msec * 1000) to round($msec * 1000000)

Comment: micro means 10^-6, milli - 10^-3

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use this function to get a Timestamp with micro seconds in PHP:

```
int microtime ( void )
```

Use it as shown in the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_microtime), following code snippet shows you how I'd altered it according to be helpful to your question:

```
<?php

function microtime_microseconds()
{
     list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
     return round(($usec * 1000) + $sec);
}

$micro_time = microtime_microseconds();

echo $micro_time;

?>
```

And also for reference regarding to that `microtime()` PHP function, please visit and read this [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Comment: Correct, have a look at php's [microtime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: @Ali thanks Ali, I updated the answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: That's the same function OP is using. `microtime` returns either a float or a string. There is no int. The w3schools example you linked to uses the string version to return a float. This is the replacement for old versions of PHP that didn't support `get_as_float = true` as a parameter to `microtime`. So, this answer doesn't solve OP's problem in any way.

Comment: @GolezTrol I understand what you said. But can you recheck the answer as I edited it once again!

Comment: Still not right, unfortunately. You need to multiply by a million to get microseconds (or change the name of the function to `microtime_milliseconds`). More importantly, you need to multiply the seconds too to get the right results. And then still, it's easier really to use the float value like I did in my answer.